# How do I set up an environment for multiple languages?

Tags: xetex, longtable, unicode, polyglossia, arabic

been trying to set up a real multilangual environment for year. Now finally I would like to get it done. Why does the following mwe not work?:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}{Calibri}[
  Script=Greek,
  NFSSFamily=liberationserif,
]
\newfontfamily{\greekfontsf}{Calibri}[
  Script=Greek,
  NFSSFamily=liberationsans,
]
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}%
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic,Scale=.75]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1,WordSpace=2]{Adobe Arabic}
\newfontfamily\mySymbolsFont{Segoe UI Symbol}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

\setotherlanguage[numerals=western]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{farsi}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Deutsch}

content does not matter

\end{document}
```

without the lines

```
\setotherlanguage[numerals=western]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{farsi}
```

it works with longtable. Adding either of them breaks it. Without longtable it works. But if I have to move away from longtable I need alternative versatile support for tables spanning multiple pages.

In the end I want an environment for a German book (all the meta strings like Chapter=Kapitel, Table of Contents=Inhaltsverzeichnis, ...) but with both inline words and sentence fragments as well as whole paragraphs in Greek (must have), Chinese (must have), Arabic (must have) and the ability to throw in other scripts later (nice to have), and English of course, but that works anyways.

I am using XeLaTeX (I want to type Chinese and Arabic naturally, => Unicode) and Biber (I have Authors and Titles in Chinese and Arabic).

Hope this time I get it done, thx for helping in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `NFSSFamily=liberationserif` and `NFSSFamily=liberationsans`? This doesn’t look like the account of the NFSSFamily feature in the `fontspec` manual.

Comment: @Thérèse: your second comment would be the answer, That I would like to mark as the solution.

Comment: Regarding parallel processing, you should take a look at `paracol`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are compiling with xetex and selecting Arabic and Farsi, `polyglossia` loads `bidi`, which wants to be loaded last.  When it’s not loaded last, it produces an error along these lines:

```
! Package bidi Error: Oops! you have loaded package longtable after
bidi package. Please load package longtable before bidi package, and
then try to run xelatex on your document again.
```

This is somewhat confusing if you’re unaware that `polyglossia` has loaded `bidi` for you. But loading `longtable` before `polyglossia` will, in effect, load `longtable` before `bidi` and fix the error.

By the way, since many Arabic fonts support Farsi as well, your document will have a more unified and harmonious appearance if you choose fewer typefaces.